# What to use instead of find_with_ids( )?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The code below displays peferctly what i want to accomplish (show store name and item name).But when i subtitute `@onedeal=@deal.find_with_ids(62)` with `@onedeal=@deal.find(params[:id])` i get an error `Couldn't find Deal without an ID`.What method should i use to fetch deal ID dynamically?The relationship between the Deal and store model is has many :through.

controller

```
  @deal=@city.deals
  @onedeal=@deal.find_with_ids(62)
  @store=@onedeal.stores.first(params[:store_id])
```

view

```
   <% @deal.each do |deal| %>
   <%=deal.item_name %>
   <%end%>
    <%=@store.store_name %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that `params[:id]` is empty. Check your `params` hash to see what it contains, and verify that your action is getting the input it expects.

You are absolutely using the `.find` method as intended, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: It doesnt show any params,it shows that it gets the city id but not the deal

Comment: Is your deal stuff wrapped in a form? Your example code doesn't show a form, if there is one, or enough information that I can tell what's being passed to the action. But, maybe I don't need to see that. Basically, somewhere, the ID of the Deal just isn't being submitted. Is it in `params[:deal_id]` by chance?

Comment: yes it is wrapped in the form.no it is not in params[:deal_id] though.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Deal.find(params[:id]) rescue nil
```